# JSDoc doesn't display a table of arguments and return value/name/description

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

I've started implementing JSDoc for my project and according to the documentation a function header like this:

```
/**
 * @name randomlyGenerateMixedCaseLetterOrSpecialCharacter1
 * @description Randomly generates an alphabetic letter from A-Z, a-z or a random special character from the input list of special characters.
 * @param {string} inputData - The list of allowable special characters that should be used to randomly select from.
 * @param {string} inputMetaData - Not used for this business rule.
 * @return {string} Randomly returns a random mixed case letter of the alphabet, or a random special character from the list of allowable special characters.
 * @NOTE: OLD implementation.
 * @author Seth Hollingsead
 * @date 2020/03/05
 */
```

Should generate a small table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   Name        |  Type  |       Description        |
-----------------------------------------------------
| inputData     | String | The list of allowable... |
| inputMetaData | String | Not used for this...     |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run JSDoc against this function it rather outputs something more like this:

> ```
> randomlyGenerateMixedCaseLetterOrSpecialCharacter1
> Randomly generates an alphabetic letter from A-Z, a-z or a random special character from the input list of special characters.
>
> Author:
> Seth Hollingsead
> Source:
> Framework/BusinessRules/Rules/characterGeneration.js, line 18
> ```

It is completely missing the `@param` & `@return` tags.

Here is the complete function, minus the body. Maybe the way I have declared the function?

```
/**
 * @name randomlyGenerateMixedCaseLetterOrSpecialCharacter1
 * @description Randomly generates an alphabetic letter from A-Z, a-z or a random special character from the input list of special characters.
 * @param {string} inputData - The list of allowable special characters that should be used to randomly select from.
 * @param {string} inputMetaData - Not used for this business rule.
 * @return {string} Randomly returns a random mixed case letter of the alphabet, or a random special character from the list of allowable special characters.
 * @NOTE: OLD implementation.
 * @author Seth Hollingsead
 * @date 2020/03/05
 */
export const randomlyGenerateMixedCaseLetterOrSpecialCharacter1 = function(inputData, inputMetaData) {
  // ...Function Body...
};
```

This is my jsdoc.json file:

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": ["src"],
    "includePattern": ".js$",
    "excludePattern": "{node_modules/|Documentation}"
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": true,
    "monospaceLinks": true
  },
  "opts": {
    "recurse": true,
    "destination": "./src/Application/NodeJS-App/Resources/Documentation",
    "template": "./jsDocTemplate"
  }
}
```

Looking back over the error logs, I didn't see any errors for this file on this line.
Of course I do see errors on my other functions, but that's just because I haven't changed the formatting of the header correctly. For example: (I know this is incorrect, but it is an example of what I know I still need to do:)

```
/**
 * @name randomlyGenerateUpperCaseLetterOrSpecialCharacter1
 * @description Randomly generates an alphabetic letter from A-Z or a random special character from the input list of special characters.
 * @param  {[String]} inputData The list of allowable special characters that should be used to randomly select from.
 * @param  {[String]} inputMetaData Not used for this business rule.
 * @return {[String]} Randomly returns a random upper case letter of the alphabet, or a random special character from the list of allowable special characters.
 * @NOTE: OLD implementation.
 * @author Seth Hollingsead
 * @date 2020/03/05
 */
export const randomlyGenerateUpperCaseLetterOrSpecialCharacter1 = function(inputData, inputMetaData) {
  // ... function body
};
```

In the above header the `@param {[String]}` should be changed to `@param {string}`, and I have many more functions to do this with, I just want to make sure I get it right before I go through scrubbing all my functions in all my files.

And the error I get for that is something like this: (Although the actual error is a bit more verbose)

> ```
> \src\Framework\BusinessRules\Rules\characterGeneration.js in line 70 with tag title "param" and text "{[String]} inputData The list of allowable special characters that should be used
> \src\Framework\BusinessRules\Rules\characterGeneration.js in line 70 with tag title "param" and text "{[String]} inputMetaData Not used for this business rule.": Invalid type expression "[
> \src\Framework\BusinessRules\Rules\characterGeneration.js in line 70 with tag title "return" and text "{[String]} Randomly returns a random upper case letter of the alphabet, or a random special character
> ```

But as I said, even after correcting that I am still not getting the `@param` & `@returns` table of meta-information from the tags.

---

**EDIT**: Version Numbers:

- npm version: 6.9.0
- node version: 10.16.3
- "jsdoc": "^3.6.4",

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!!
Cheers & Stay Safe!!

---

**UPDATE**: I was able to get it to work for one of my functions, so I guess my question now becomes why does it work for one function but not the others?

Here is the header for the function I was able to make it work:

```
/**
 * Converts a time interval into a different kind of format.
 * @param {integer} deltaTime - A time interval measured in microseconds.
 * @param {string} format - The formatting template that should be used to format the time interval.
 * @return {string} A time interval formatted according to the input format template string.
 * @author Seth Hollingsead
 * @date 2020/05/21
 */
function reformatDeltaTime(deltaTime, format) {
  // ... function body...
}
```

Additionally when the same function header looks like this:

```
/**
 * @name reformatDeltaTime
 * @description Converts a time interval into a different kind of format.
 * @param {integer} deltaTime - A time interval measured in microseconds.
 * @param {string} format - The formatting template that should be used to format the time interval.
 * @return {string} A time interval formatted according to the input format template string.
 * @author Seth Hollingsead
 * @date 2020/05/21
 */
function reformatDeltaTime(deltaTime, format) {
  // ...function body
}
```

It does not work, but supposedly JSDocs is supposed to support the `@name` & `@description` tags? So what gives? Again I re-iterate....why one header format and not the other? And are there any configuration changes I can make to support the header with the `@name` and `@description` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow ok I suppose I need to read a bit more on the documentation. Always a good idea....LOL

Copy-pasted from the JSDoc documentation:
Link: [JSDoc @Name Tage Usage](https://jsdoc.app/tags-name.html)

> The @name tag forces JSDoc to associate the remainder of the JSDoc comment with the given name, ignoring all surrounding code. This tag is best used in "virtual comments" for symbols that are not readily visible in the code, such as methods that are generated at runtime.
>
> When you use the @name tag, you must provide additional tags that tell JSDoc what kind of symbol you are documenting; whether the symbol is a member of another symbol; and so on. If you do not provide this information, the symbol will not be documented correctly.
>
> Warning: By using the @name tag, you are telling JSDoc to ignore the surrounding code and treat your documentation comment in isolation. In many cases, it is best to use the @alias tag instead, which changes a symbol's name in the documentation but preserves other information about the symbol.

So I just removed the @name tag and it works correctly for my usual function header that would look like this:

```
/**
 * @description Returns a time stamp string formatted according to the input formatting string.
 * @param {string} formatting The formatting string, that tells moment in what format to return the value for the day, month, year, hour, minute, and second.
 * @return {string} A time stamp string that has been formatted according to the input format.
 * @author Seth Hollingsead
 * @date 2020/05/21
 */
function getNowMoment(formatting) {
  // ...function body...
};
```

However, it still doesn't work for functions defined like this:

```
export const generateRandomMixedCaseTextByLength1 = function(inputData, inputMetaData) {
  // ...function body...
};
```

Apparently the solution to this is to just use the `@function` tag in place of the `@name` tag. Here it is described in the JSDoc documentation: [@function tag documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-function.html)

So the header for this document should look like:

```
/**
 * @function generateRandomMixedCaseTextByLength1
 * @description Parse the input string, and determine how many mixed case alphabetic characters should be generated, generate them and string them together.
 * @param {string} inputData The string that contains a number or how many randomly generated mixed case alphabetic characters should be generated.
 * @param {string} inputMetaData Not used for this business rule.
 * @return {string} A string of randomly generated mixed case letters where the length of the string is defined by the input parameter.
 * @NOTE: OLD implementation
 * @author Seth Hollingsead
 * @date 2020/03/04
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue!

TLDR;

The solution was to add @module at the start of the file.
https://jsdoc.app/howto-es2015-modules.html

Long answer:

So if you write your modules like that:

```
module.export = {
/** 
* @description some Function
* @param none 
*/
someFunction {},
/** 
* @description some Function
* @param none 
*/
someOtherFunction {}
}
```

Jsdoc does not understand that you implement functions.
@function did not help me with that.

Adding the line at the start of the file

```
/** @module someFunctions */
```

will tell jsdoc that the documentation is for a module and jsdoc will generate function descriptions.

The issue can also be solved with defining the functions and them exporting them.